# change background image of webkit-slider-thumb by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, background-image

I searched for a while but couldn't find anything useful.I have the following css

```
 input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
       -webkit-appearance: none;
         width: 20px;
         height: 20px;
         border-radius: 10px;
         background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.png'),
         -webkit-gradient(
             linear,
             left top,
             left bottom,
             color-stop(0, #fefefe),
             color-stop(0.49, #dddddd),
             color-stop(0.51, #d1d1d1),
             color-stop(1, #a1a1a1)
         );
         background-size:20px;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

Now I want to change the background image to some other image src by the help of jquery or plain javascript which I can test from chrome console.So that I have something like:

```
`background-image: url('http://someotherimage/test.png'),`
```

Could anyone please mention the correct syntax.
Thanking you in anticipation of favorable response.

Comment: FYI, it's "with jQuery" not "by jquery". The little words are the hardest to learn in another language!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder which ever gets the job done

Comment: Aameer: The point is that "by jquery" is wrong.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is it possible to do it by  plain javascript ? if yes, then that will also work for me.if no, then is there any other way to change  it dynamically? & Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am posting solution which worked for me for anyone facing the same issue.As I wanted to change the css of the -webkit-slider-thumb on the fly so I did something like this I used a class for  the input and added css for this class like this

```
.first_class::-webkit-slider-thumb {
           -webkit-appearance: none;
             width: 20px;
             height: 20px;

             border-radius: 10px;
             background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.png'),
             -webkit-gradient(
                 linear,
                 left top,
                 left bottom,
                 color-stop(0, #fefefe),
                 color-stop(0.49, #dddddd),
                 color-stop(0.51, #d1d1d1),
                 color-stop(1, #a1a1a1)
             );
             background-size:20px;
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-position: 50%;
         }
```

I also added the other set of css under a different class name like this

```
.second_class::-webkit-slider-thumb {
       -webkit-appearance: none;
         width: 20px;
         height: 20px;

         border-radius: 10px;
         background-image: url('http://someotherimage/test.png'),
         -webkit-gradient(
             linear,
             left top,
             left bottom,
             color-stop(0, #fefefe),
             color-stop(0.49, #dddddd),
             color-stop(0.51, #d1d1d1),
             color-stop(1, #a1a1a1)
         );
         background-size:20px;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: 50%;
     }
```

Then using Jquery I changed the classes whenever I needed to change the css, i.e if I remove the `first_class` and add `second_class` to the input  it *will change the image of the -webkit-slider-thumb*
Thankyou for all those who tried to help.

Answer (score 7):

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QneFV.png) center center no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -23px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #367ebd;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QneFV.png) center center no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -23px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2a6495;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3071a9;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QneFV.png) center center no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -23px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3071a9;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #367ebd;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a little hack way to help you.

Here I have write a same selector as `input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb` in a `<style>` tag, and append it to the last of `<head>`.

And then, this style will cover the `background-image` you ever write.

```
$('<style>input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb { background-image: url("http://someotherimage/test.png");}<style/>').appendTo('head');
```

[jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/edisonator/99KKr/2/)

I have updated my anwser as T.J.

Comment: Not really hacky, as it's the only way you can do it. There's no direct way to set the style of pseudo-elements, you *have* to use a style rule. I wouldn't set the CSS content with `html()`, though, I'm not sure that's reliable. Parsing the whole tag is reliable, though, so: `$("<style>/* ...CSS content...*/</style>").appendTo('head');`

Answer (score 0):

There is now a CSS3 way of doing this which I think is much simpler and cleaner.

In your HTML tag you define a `style` tag such as:

`style="--img-path:url('/images/small_blue_inner.svg') no-repeat 8px 8px #fff;"`

In your CSS stylesheet your background would then read:

`background:var(--img-path);`

You can then set your style attribute with jquery the way you normally would:

`$(slider).attr('style',"--img-path:url('/images/small_ALT_Img.svg') no-repeat 8px 8px #fff;--img-border:1px solid #11b6d1");`

And as you can use these in pseudo elements I believe this is the best solution for 2018.